# __str__ method for a tic-tac-toe board

Tags: python, python-3.x, formatting, tic-tac-toe, ascii-art

I am making my first object-oriented program in python and I am having trouble with the `__str__` part of `Board()` class. I want it to be a visual representation of the tic-tac-toe board. I have achieved this but the code looks ridiculous and I know there must be a better way! Here is my project so far:

```
class Space(object):

    def __init__(self, state="x"):
        self.state = state

    state_names = ['empty', 'x', 'o']

    def __str__(self):

        return str(self.state)

    def change_state(self, string):
        if string == 'x':
            self.state = 'x'
        else:
            self.state = 'o'

class Board(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.spaces = []
        for num in range(0,9):
            space = Space()
            self.spaces.append(space)
        board = self.spaces

    def __str__(self):
        res = []
        for space in self.spaces:
            res.append(str(space))
        return '   |   |'  + '\n ' + res[6] + ' | ' + res[7] + ' | ' + res[8] + '\n   |   |' + '\n-----------' + '\n   |   |' + '\n ' + res[3] + ' | ' + res[4] + ' | ' + res[5] + '\n   |   |' + '\n-----------' + '\n   |   |' + '\n ' + res[0] + ' | ' + res[1] + ' | ' + res[2] + '\n   |   |'
```

the default output should (and does) look like this:

```
   |   |
 x | x | x
   |   |
-----------
   |   |
 x | x | x
   |   |
-----------
   |   |
 x | x | x
   |   |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though not according the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) and debatable for [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), I would do something like (*Readability counts*):

```
def __str__(self):
    s = ('   |   |   \n' +
         ' # | # | # \n' +
         '   |   |   \n' +
         '---+---+---\n' +
         '   |   |   \n' +
         ' # | # | # \n' +  
         '   |   |   \n' +
         '---+---+---\n' +
         '   |   |   \n' +
         ' # | # | # \n' +
         '   |   |   '  ).replace('#', '{}')
    return s.format(* map(str, self.spaces))
```

(btw.: I messed up the order of `self.spaces`)

(note: the asterisk in `s.format(* map(...` *unpacks* the list returned by `map` into individual arguments for `format`)

A bit more 'DRYer' solution would be:

```
    l1 = '   |   |   '
    l2 = ' {} | {} | {} '
    l3 = '---+---+---'
    s = '\n'.join([l1, l2, l1, l3, l1, l2, l1, l3, l1, l2, l1])
```

Comment: Quite readable! I highly recommend the first approach over the second though, although perhaps using a multi-line string instead. If the layout would have to change, this is easy to change. The "DRY" (in quotes, as I do not believe it to be DRY) approach would be harder to update.

Answer (score 2):

You can hugely reduce your `__str__` using loops, e.g. using `join()` and a couple of generator expressions:

```
def __str__(self):
    return '\n-----------\n'.join('   |   |\n '+' | '.join(str(self.spaces[x]) for x in [0+y, 1+y, 2+y])+'\n   |   |' for y in [6, 3, 0])
```

Output:

```
   |   |
 x | x | x
   |   |
-----------
   |   |
 x | x | x
   |   |
-----------
   |   |
 x | x | x
   |   |
```